# Need to either convert RAW print data to ps/pdf or print it from Java

Tags: java, perl, printing

Our application is a client/server setup, where the client is a standalone Java application that always runs in Windows, and the server is written in C and can run on either a Windows or a Unix machine.  Additionally, we use Perl for doing various reports.  Generally, the way the reports work is that we generate either a text file or an xml file on the server in Perl and then send that to the client.  The client then uses FOP or similar to convert the xml into a pdf.  In either the case of the text file or the eventual pdf, the user select a printer via the java client and then the copied over file prints to the selected printer.

One of our "reports" is used for creating barcodes.  This one is different in that it uses Perl to fetch/format some data from the database and then sends that to a C application that creates some Raw print data.  This data is then sent directly to the printer (via a simple pipe in Unix or a custom application in Windows.

The problem is that this in no way respects the printer selected by the user in the Java client.  Also, we are unable to show a preview in said client.  Ideally, I'd like to be able convert the raw print data into a ps/pdf or similar on the server (or even on the client) and then send THAT to the printer from the client.  This would allow me to show a preview as well as actually print to the selected printer.

If I can't generate a preview, even just copying over the raw data in a file to the Java client and then sending that to the printer would probably be "good enough."  I've been unable to find anything that is quite what I'm trying to accomplish so any help would of course be appreciated.

Edit: The RAW data is in PCL format.  I managed to reconcile the source with a PCL language reference guide.

Comment: What is the format of the RAW print data?

Comment: That's a good question and also one I don't know the answer to.  I have the source file that generates the data, but don't know enough about it to even know what to look for or how to answer the question.

Comment: I opened up the data in the OpenPCL viewer... it didn't look quite right, but it was mostly there.  Seems like I could assume that it is PCL or similar...

Comment: Apparently the step you need to remove is the custom C application that output raw printer files. What does this application does exactly?

Comment: It merely takes the data and and prints the PCL data out to STDOUT.  I'm thinking you are correct though... I'm looking into some other ideas, e.g. changing this app to print in postscript language, using the barcode plugin for FOP, or even just using a barcode font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to generate the barcodes using XSL-FO directly.  This is the "correct" answer based on our architecture and trying to do anything else would have been just a dirty hack.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/)?

Comment: I haven't, although it's not really feasible for me to bring in any new third party libraries here due to the scope of the current install base.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Jon: Seems legitimate as it is a pointer to a tool that could have helped to solve the OP question, even if not an actual complete answer.

Comment: @deli the format of stackoverflow is not a link farm. Answers here are expected to explain what they reference. Just a link does not meet that expectation. Its a useful link, it just needs to be explained to be a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You willl need to find some way of interpreting the RAW format, which most likely is some printer language like PCL or HPGL into a format you can use.  This is probably best done at serverside.

A java based PCL interpreter can be found at http://openpcl.sourceforge.net/ - I have no experience with it.